# Sql count distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I am trying to count distinct values grouped by different column
this is my table: product

| id | typePr | namePr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | typeA | nameA |
| 2 | typeeB | nameC |
| 3 | typeA | nameB |
| 4 | typeA | nameB |
| 5 | typeB | nameA |
| 6 | typeB | nameC |
| 7 | typeC | nameB |

I wanna get something like this :

[{"typePr":"typeA","nameA":"1","nameB":"2"}, {"typePr":"typeB","nameC":"2","nameA":"1"} , {"typePr":"typeC","nameB":"1"} ]

is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Please _edit_ and reveal the real question.

Comment: my bad on that sorry, I did and I don't know anymore if it is doable ...

Comment: Are you using PHP here or just MySQL directly?

Comment: I am using php, the format doesnt matter that much I think what I need first is how to get the needed results , right ?

Answer (score 1):

The general query you want here uses `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT age, SUM(gender = 'F') AS countF, SUM(gender = 'H') AS countH
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY age;
```

As for turning your result set into JSON, you could try to do this from MySQL, but more typically you would handle this from your presentation layer (e.g. PHP).

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to replace that 'SUM(gender = 'F')' and 'SUM(gender = 'H')' with an other that can looks for the distinct values from a column , I mean I am not using this only for H and F, please ..

Comment: How many different distinct values appear in the gender column?

Comment: I am not using this for gender column actually I don't know how many distinct values can be, since I am using this for custom dashboarding based on selected columns by the user,

Comment: Then you asked the wrong question.  We need some other approach.